# Creating table with values in Java Derby

Tags: java, sql, loops, derby

I am trying to create a table with values that are in a String array. I am looking for the best way to loop through it without having to send a bunch of queries. This is what I have but obviously the loop wont work. Anyone have a better way of performing this?

```
    public static void createTable(String table, String[] values) throws SQLException{
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        Statement state = conn.createStatement();

        for(int x = 0; x < values.length; x++){

            state.execute("CREATE TABLE" + table + " ( " + values[x] + " );");
        }
        conn.commit();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't help the loop problem. Good catch though. That could have caused problems. Thanks! Anyone have any ideas for looping this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the elements of Values array.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.append("CREATE TABLE " + table + " ( ");

 for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   sb.append(values[i]);
   if (i >= values.length-1) {break;}
  sb.append(",");
 }
 sb.append(" )");
 state.execute(sb.toString());
```

Comment: so even though that loop states that it will do 'CREATE TABLE ' every time, it shouldn't cause problems to the database or will it just through an error?

Comment: It also looks like I get a weird error I don't seem to understand.